# How to make UI Element show when colliding with a gameobject

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

I have a GameObject (a sword). When my character is colliding with the swords collider I want the UI to show an icon (the key that has to be pressed to interact with the gameobject).
How can I do that?

I don t know how to implement it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside of a script attached to your sword, create a variable of type `GameObject` and assign it to your UI element in the inspector.

Then call `.SetActive(true)` on this variable when you detect that the player enter in collision with the sword.

To detect that you can use [OnCollisionEnter](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter.html), or [OnTriggerEnter](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter.html) in case your sword's collider is a trigger. Or the 2D equivalent if you are in a 2D game ([OnCollisionEnter2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter2D.html) or [OnTriggerEnter2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter2D.html))

And finally use [OnCollisionExit.](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionExit.html) (or trigger / 2D equivalent) to disable it again when the player leaves.

So basically:

```cs
using UnityEngine;


public class Sword : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    [SerializeField] GameObject swordUi;

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        // assuming your player has the "Player" tag
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            swordUi.SetActive(true);
        }
    }


    void OnCollisionExit(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            swordUi.SetActive(false);
        }
    }

}
```